# How do I execute a function when I receive a "push notification" with the application closed?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, nativescript

I have a problem, I need to do that when I receive a push notification some method / service / something that I open the application and start sounding an alarm is launched. It is an application to alert firefighters in the event of a fire. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: For notification you can go through this link
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

Comment: You might find it is better to ask separate questions when you have a cross-platform issue, as the solutions for Android and iOS will be different.  You could also provide more information on any research you have done and a specific concern or issue that has arisen as a result of that research or an attempted implementation.

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService) link . notificationListner receives calls from the system when new notifications are posted or removed, or their ranking changed.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using firebase plugin? If yes, send data message instead of notification so your message received callback will be called as soon it's received, but you will have to take care displaying notification on your own.